# Чат поиска работы

Tags: предложение, чат

Тут мысль пришла в голову:

У нас на ресурсе уже есть чаты, которые отличны от общей тематики сайта, например политота.

А почему бы не намутить чат поиска работы?

Скажем, какому-нибудь участник кто-то нужен в его команду и он оставляет вакансию в чате.

Другой участник, видя вакансию может на нее откликнутся.

Сам по себе профиль на SO может сказать многое о соискателе.

Comment: Ну так создайте, не думаю, что для этого нужно что-то обсуждать здесь на мете

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да просто решил поспрашивать разделяет ли кто-то мою идею или нет :)

Comment: Другой вопрос, что об этом чате никто не будет знать и можно ли где-то на видном месте разместить ссылку на этот чат. Но это уже политический вопрос. Да и у SO есть своя платформа с вакансиями

Comment: @АндрейNOP Что-то мне подсказывает, что там только зарубежные тусуются.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?l=Moscow%2C+%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F&d=100&u=Km

Comment: @АндрейNOP ого.

Comment: Можно создать. А чат с политотой в целом вообще на грани. Такого чата по правилам главного SO в принципе быть не должно (:

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica намутил https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104047/

Comment: @iluxa1810 учитывая, что у нас в чате плюс-минус одни и те же люди сидят, и их не более 10, то толку от чата не особо)